# How to Publish Mule Application to Exchange as Connector in Mule 4

Tags: mule4, audit-logging, anypoint-platform, mule-connector, mule-sdk

I need to publish mule application to exchange as connector in mule 4.
Could anyone please let me know the process.

Answer (score 1):

You can't publish an application to Anypoint Exchange and expect it to be used as a connector. An application and a connector are different artifacts, are created differently and work differently.

What you can do is to create an actual connector with the [XML SDK](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/xml-sdk), and try to adapt the flows of your application into the format required by the XML SDK, which is similar to application's flows but instead defines operations, with inputs and outputs.